# How to hide grid action button from "sw-entity-listing" listing in shopware 6?

Tags: plugins, grid, edit, shopware

How to hide grid action buttons(Edit, Delete) from "sw-entity-listing" listing in shopware 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to hide the whole actions column you can do this with the prop `showActions`. This would be the most simple way.

```
<sw-entity-listing 
    :showActions="false">
</sw-entity-listing>
```

If you only want to hide the "edit" or "delete" button and not the whole actions column you can override the slots `delete-action` or `detail-action` with an empty tag or something else:

```
<sw-entity-listing>
    <template #delete-action>
        My content
    </template>
</sw-entity-listing>

<sw-entity-listing>
    <template #delete-action>
        <span></span> <!-- No action here -->
    </template>
</sw-entity-listing>
```

The `sw-entity-lising` component is an extension of the `sw-data-grid` component. So in general you can use all props from `sw-data-grid` as well.

Comment: Thank you, Tobias

I have tried this. the edit and delete buttons are hidden now but the ... the button is still showing. Is there any way to hide that button also?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no Vue slot for the button itself so you have to consider another solution here.

You could wait for the component to render via `mounted()` hook and delete the menu buttons manually via JavaScript `document.querySelectorAll('.sw-data-grid__actions-menu').forEach(item => item.remove())`

This is hacky of course but it does the job.

Comment: Usually you can use the Twig `{% block %}` tags to override desired template parts. But in this case the `sw-entity-listing` is already overriding blocks from the `sw-data-grid` which makes it inaccessible for another extend of `sw-entity-lising`.

However if you want to get rid of the buttons anyway, could you use the `showActions` prop which hides the whole action column? Or do you want to keep the column with empty content for each row? Maybe you could explain a bit more what you want to achieve.